# How to embed Adobe cirrus app with PHP/MySQL website

Tags: php, mysql, adobe, adobe-cirrus, soundcloud-stratus

Sample application link - [click Here to see the adobe application](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/samples/) with this application I want to build video chatting functionality in my site. How to embed this application using php/MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial:

http://active6.com/actionscript/the-adobe-stratus-beta-sample-app-and-phpmysql

It is discussed here:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/28893

Comment: Thank u friend. 
but problem is that when I click on download link from http://active6.com/actionscript/the-adobe-stratus-beta-sample-app-and-phpmysql at that time displays "404- Page not found" error.

Comment: It should be possible to get it up and running without the zip file - in either case you need to understand the PHP code show in the tutorial, otherwise it will be too hard for you to adapt it to your use case. This is not a simple copy/paste problem unfortunately.

Comment: I am new in this field. and have no idea how to build this.

Comment: Honestly - try to find someone who does it for you. It's not a beginner's topic.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Cirrus + PHP and MySQL.
https://github.com/EddyF/eddyf_videochat

Comment: Eddy Ferreira Thanks.
Can you describe me how to implement it ?

Comment: Hi JD, you shouldnt run into any problems if you follow the installation instructions on the link I sent you